# Correlation Matrix for Very Large Data Set

Tags: python, r, correlation

I am tasked to create a correlation matrix on a large portion of an MRI imaging data set (all numeric entries). The dimensions of the data is around 28,000x1,800. I have already set a correlation threshold of 0.5, and excluded diagonal values, to reduce the number of outputs. However, the number of correlations remaining is extremely high. A correlation plot would still be extremely messy and unreadable.

What can I do to produce something clean and useful? Any suggestions?

Comment: [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298108/how-to-analyze-correlation-on-high-dimensional-data) might help you.